# Replacing for-loops using thrust::transform

Tags: c++, for-loop, cuda, thrust, odeint

I am trying to optimize my code by implementing for loops on threads of the GPU. I am trying to eliminate two for loops using thrust::transform. The code in C++ looks like:

```
    ka_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_gene; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_ka_d[i]; j++ )
        {
            co0 = get_coeff0(ka_vec_d[ka_index]);
            act[i] += (co0*ka_val_d[ka_index]); 
            ka_index++;
        }
        act[i] = pow(act[i],n); 
    }
```

I am estimating co-efficients for an ordinary differential equation(ODE) in the above loops
and have transferred all the data onto the device using thrust. Consider the case where the number of genes is represented by N_gene. The fist for loop has to run N_gene number of times. The second for loop is restricted by the number of activators(other friendly genes in the gene pool) of each gene. Each gene has a number of activators(friendly genes whose presence increases the concentration of gene i) represented by elements of n_ka vector. Value of n_ka[i] can vary from 0 to N_gene - 1.  ka_val represents the measure of activation for each activator ka. ka_vec_d has the gene index which activates gene i.

I am trying to represent these loops using iterators, but unable to do so. I am familiar with using thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple)) for a single for loop, but having a tough time coming up with a way to implement two for loops using counting_iterator or transform iterators. Any pointers or help to convert these two for loops will be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a reduce problem. I think you can use `thrust::transform` with zip iterators and `thrust::reduce_by_key`. A sketch of this solution is:

```
// generate indices
std::vector< int > hindices;
for( size_t i=0 ; i<N_gene ; ++i )
    for( size_t j=0 ; j<n_ka_d[i] ; ++j )
     hindices.push_back( i );
thrust::device_vector< int > indices = hindices;

// generate tmp
// trafo1 implements get_coeff0( get< 0 >( t ) ) * get< 1 >( t);
thrust::device_vector< double > tmp( N );
thrust::transform(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple( ka_vec_d.begin() , ka_val_d.begin() ) ) ,
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple( ka_vec_d.end() , ka_val_d.end() ) ) ,
    tmp.begin() , trafo1 );

// do the reduction for each ac[i]
thrust::device_vector< int > indices_out( N );
thrust::reduce_by_key( indices.begin() , indices.end() , tmp.begin() ,
    ac.begin() , indices_out.begin() );

// do the pow transformation
thrust::transform( ac.begin() , ac.end() , ac.begin() , pow_trafo );
```

I this this can also be optimized by transform_iterators to reduce the number of calls of `thrust::transform` and `thrust::recuce_by_key`.

Comment: Thanks headmyshouder, this surely helps and I have already implemented it using reduce_by_key and my application is running fine. I made a small change in a sense using thrust::for_each instead of thrust::transform and integrating tmp into the tuple used to generate tmp. Is there any advantage using thrust::transform over thrust::for_each? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: I think there is no real difference. thrust::transform is a bit more expressiveness since it tells you what is happening. You could also try to measure if the performance of both ways is equal.